# Lightning Data Service (Beta) Available?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am currently checking `force:recordData` tag and I cannot find any information if this is available on PROD orgs or not, as in a documentation it doesn't say anything about it, but on the release notes page for Lightning Data Service it mentions that the whole LDS is still [beta](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_data_service.htm?edition=&impact=)
Can I safely use it and then deploy to my PROD org or is it not possible?
How are the beta features managed and where can I find any info about what's available for PROD and what is not?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Lightning Data Service is only available in Lightning Experience and
>   Salesforce1. Using Lightning Data Service in other containers, such as
>   Lightning Components for Visualforce, Lightning Out, or Communities
>   isn’t supported. This is true even if these containers are accessed
>   inside Lightning Experience or Salesforce1, for example, a Visualforce
>   page added to Lightning Experience.

It is available if your Org is in Summer '17.

You can read more from the [Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm).